# Using correct quotation marks in formula code

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I want to use 2 variables of 2 lines as part of a formula to be entered into Excel. I keep getting a syntax error which makes me think I have the quotation marks all in the wrong places.

I have tried every single permutation for quotation marks with no success.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("O" & Week_LastLine).Formula = "=MIN("I" & Week_TopLine & "":"" & "I" & Week_LastLine)+5000"
```

I need the formula `=Min(I10..I20)+5000` to be entered where the 10 and 20 are derived from variables. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Try this:  "=MIN(I" & Week_TopLine & ":I" & Week_LastLine & ")+5000"

Comment: @BrianMStafford: That should go as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correctly stringing items together can sometimes be tricky.  In this case, the answer would be:

```
"=MIN(I" & Week_TopLine & ":I" & Week_LastLine & ")+5000"
```

Sometimes I solve the problem as follows.  Our starting point is:

```
"=Min(I10:I20)+5000"
```

Since we need to replace the 10 and 20 with variables, I isolate them first:

```
"=Min(I" & "10" & ":I" & "20" & ")+5000"
```

At this point the two strings still give the same result.  Now simply replace the "10" and "20" with your variables.

Comment: Thanks
That was exactly what I needed to know.
Brilliant!

Comment: @RobDavidowitz If an answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark and upvoting by clicking the up arrow. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. There is no obligation to do this.